# 2sxc App | Demo Content | Auto Fill

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I have a series of modules based on the 'Content' App that I have created demo content for but as per the templates once I click edit the content data doesn't pre fill into the UI fields (which is something I'm trying to achieve).

I know the 'Content' App module templates are not Apps on their own like the 'FAQ'/'Accordion' Apps which I thought were capable of this pre fill presentation of demo content. How do you set an App's demo presentation content to display in the input fields of the UI?

I am currently looking at the Visual Query Designer but is this the only way to assign demo content to auto fill into the UI fields once a user clicks edit?

**NOTE:** *My goal is to create a dnn template page of modules all displaying demo content (each assigned its own one) and then either copy this page or import it to another whereby the demo content has actually pre filled the modules on the new page once a user clicks on the edit button.*

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can go to the "fields" of the content type and click on the "data type" ie sting, hyperlink etc and you should be able to set a default value

Comment: Thx! That works great...... as long as I create a new App for each new demo content module that I want unique single instance pre filled content to appear.